# VBA Excel - Hiding Rows when saving to PDF still includes a blank sheet for the rows.

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I have a list of dropdown variables, and dependant on their Yes/No certain rows below are kept or hidden from the printable document.

```
  If Range("D5") = "No" Then
Rows("51:100").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

If Range("D6") = "No" Then
Rows("101:150").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

If Range("D7") = "No" Then
Rows("151:200").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```

I then publish to pdf as follows:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "File.pdf", Quality:= _
        xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

My issue is, that when I publish to PDF, any rows which are hidden as per the IF statements are still included but as a blank page. So if I have 20 sections, but only click Yes two include 2 of them, my document will still be 20 pages long but only two would have information on and the other 18 of those would be blank.

Weirdly, this problem is avoided if I manually hide the rows, but the coding is still the same for the action (based on Record Macro).

I'm assuming given the manual success, that it's something to do with the active areas but I can't nail it. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: Code worked for me as is. Does it help if you explicitly define the worksheet you consider. For example: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows("51:100").Hidden = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D5") = "No"`? *(Notice how I also too out the unncessary `If` block and `Select` statements as well)*

Comment: i have run your Code and i have no issue...

Comment: I've tried it again and also with Scott's coding and it still including the blank pages. I've even tried to a basic file version [LINK TO GOOGLE DRIVE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1syGrdwCYnrnS77Zq0u72qBXkN_5kP0Aq/view?usp=sharing). Perhaps someone may see something I've missed?